# JQuery is not getting fired when <li> is constructed programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please have a look at my JavaScript

```
<script>
            function dynamicMessageLoader(id) {

                $.get("SentMessagesDynamicLoaderServlet?idMessageGroup=" + id, function (responseJson) {

                    $('#li_list').empty();
                    var array = [];

                    $.each(responseJson, function (index, item)

                    {
                        array[index] = item;
                    });

                    $('#message_count').empty();

                    var readArray = array.length;
                    var count = readArray + " Messages Selected";
                    $('<p />', {html: count}).appendTo('#message_count');

                    for (var i = 0; i < readArray; i++) {

                        //$('<li />', {html: array[i][1]}).appendTo('#li_list');
                        $('<li>', { 'class': 'clickable-row hand', id: array[i][0], html: array[i][1]}).appendTo('#li_list');

                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Now the associated HTML

```
<ul id="li_list">
<li class='clickable-row hand' id="12" >text</li>                                  
</ul>
```

What happens is that when the above JavaScript code gets called, it adds `<li>` elements to `li_list`. As you can see, I have already hard coded one `<li>` element there as well.

Now when the `<li>` element is called, the below `Jquery` code needs to be executed.

```
<script>

            jQuery(function () {
                $('.clickable-row').click(function () {


                    var $this = $(this),
                            id = this.id;

                    //alert(id);

                    $.get("MessagesDynamicPopupServlet?idMessage=" + id, function (responseJson) {

                        var array = [];

                        $.each(responseJson, function (index, item)

                        {
                            array[index] = item;
                        });
                        var image = array[3];

                        $('#idMessage').val(array[0]);
                        $('#idMessageGroup').val(array[1]);
                        $('#message').val(array[2]);

                        $('#blah').attr("src", image);

                        $('#videoURL').val(array[4]);
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
```

Now the thing is, the above Jquery code gets called only for the hard coded `<li>`. It never gets called for the `<li>` element I added via the JavaScript.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to register the on click function after adding the "li" manually.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [Delegated events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)  , for the newly created elements . so here you'll attach an event  to a parent (`document` in this case ) ,  that will be fired for all it's descendants ( second params in the `.on` function )  which will be the `.clickable-row` class in your case .

It wont work for `$('.clickable-row').click` because this last is attached to only existing dom node at the moment of the event assignment ( so newly created wont be attached to this click ).

See below code :

```
$(document).on("click", '.clickable-row', function() {


  var $this = $(this),
    id = this.id;

  //alert(id);

  $.get("MessagesDynamicPopupServlet?idMessage=" + id, function(responseJson) {

    var array = [];

    $.each(responseJson, function(index, item)

      {
        array[index] = item;
      });
    var image = array[3];

    $('#idMessage').val(array[0]);
    $('#idMessageGroup').val(array[1]);
    $('#message').val(array[2]);

    $('#blah').attr("src", image);

    $('#videoURL').val(array[4]);
  });
});
```

Comment: if you dont mind would you explain why this works ?

Comment: Okey i'll do now

Comment: wow great. Yes, please explain why this works too.

Comment: @PeakGen added in answer :)

Comment: When you call `$('.clickable-row')` it will search all such elements and attach events (like 'click'). It will do so only for existing objects. When you use `$(document).on("click", '.clickable-row', function(){});` It will attach event on `document` (which always exists), and when you click on `.clickable-row` this click event will bubble down to document where script checks which element was clicked and executes attached event.